# How to use element id as JS function parameter in `onclick` function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use my an anchor tag as a button running a JS function when clicked.

HTML -

```
<a  class="ghost-button-transition" href="#" onclick="navforward(about)" style="margin-right:5px;">About me</a>
```

JS -

```
function navforward(name){
  var str = "#"+String(name);
  $("#intro").fadeOut(1000).delay(1500);
  $(str).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Whenever I click on my `<a>` tag I get the following error in the console -

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]

Now I understand that this is happening because my `navforward` function is treating the `name` parameter as an object and hence can't really use it as a handle to call the respective HTML element. But why isn't it working even after converting the parameter to a string?

I have also tried- `onclick="navforward("about")` and `onclick="navforward("#about")` but they also gave errors.

How do I get this working?

Comment: `var str = "#"+name.id;`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much

Comment: @YaddyVirus, Just use `$(name).fadeIn(1000)` no need to create ID selector

Comment: @Satpal How did I not try that? Works just fine

Answer (score 3):

Your `about` object is an `HTMLDivElement`.

Just use its `id` property instead of converting it to a String :

```
function navforward(name){
  let str = "#"+name.id;
  $("#intro").fadeOut(1000).delay(1500);
  $(str).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

---

As *@Satpal* pointed out in the comments, you can simply use your `about` object directly in your jQuery selector :

```
function navforward(name){
  $("#intro").fadeOut(1000).delay(1500);
  $(name).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: Why not simple `$(name).fadeIn(1000)`? As `about` is `HTMLDivElement` not need to get its id then use ID selector

Answer (score 0):

Pass about as a string as:

HTML:

```
<a class="ghost-button-transition" href="#" onclick="navforward('about')" style="margin-right:5px;">About me</a>
```

JS:

```
function navforward(name){
  var str = "#"+name;
  $("#intro").fadeOut(1000).delay(1500);
  $(str).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: You want to fade in this anchor or some other element with about id? show the element with this id

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. If you pass `this` object in a method, you can access the whole DOM element.

```
<a id="about" class="ghost-button-transition" href="#" onclick="navforward(this)" style="margin-right:5px;">About me</a>

function navforward(obj){
  $("#" + obj.id).fadeOut(1000).delay(1500).fadeIn(1000);
}
```